# Laravel Vue.js application not running

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, npm

I have a serious problem on running Laravel + Vue.js new applications. I tried that on a 50% developed app and also on a brand new Laravel instalation and that shows the same error. After installing the Laravel and going into php artisan serve i start a common routine to start Vue.js within that Laravel application, which means `NPM RUN INSTALL` and right after `NPM RUN DEV`. This is what the errors show me:

[image]
[image]

I have tried all possible solutions found on previous posts on Stack Overflow and Github but the error persists. I have a node version 10.15.1 and the latest Laravel scaffold. Any thoughts on what might be happening? Im at the point of giving up using a scaffold Vue.js and instead using it as stand alone.

Thank you!

Comment: i installed the Vue compiler man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like, It fails while `vue-template-compiler` package getting install through yarn.

It might be issue with yarn in your system.
Try to first install `vue-template-compiler` through NPM:

- `npm install vue-template-compiler`

Then try again with `npm run dev`.

I hope this will help.

Comment: You are a legend Dude!! :)